# React does not render new states at their updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When updating a state, react does not re-render the screen.  Moreover, the use effect is not called.

[image]

When clicking on the "change" button, react does not seem to want to re-render with the new values. Also, the use effect is not called.

```js
const [identity, setIdentity] = useState([{id: 1, name: "Lucas"}, {id: 2, name: "Jean"}]);
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("UPDATE");
}, [identity]);
```

But when another state changes, the screen is updated.

You can try this CodeSandBox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-frog-su3m30?file=/src/App.js

I have a hunch, maybe I'm not using the right method to change the value of my object.

```js
function handleChange(evt) {
    const toEdit = identity;
    const index = toEdit.findIndex(predicate => predicate.id = 1);
    toEdit[index] = {...toEdit[index], name: "Michel"}
    console.log({index, toEdit});
    setIdentity(toEdit);
}
```

Comment: React doesn't know when the items in an array change, you need to pass an entirely new array to `setIdentity()` (`const toEdit = identity;` sets `toEdit` to reference the same array under the hood, it doesn't create a copy)

Comment: Try `const toEdit = [...identity];`. With your current code, `toEdit` and `identity` are references to the very same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is state mutation with `toEdit[index] = {...toEdit[index], name: "Michel"}`. `toEdit` is a reference to the existing state `identity`.

```
function handleChange(evt) {
  const toEdit = identity;
  const index = toEdit.findIndex(predicate => predicate.id = 1);
  toEdit[index] = {...toEdit[index], name: "Michel"}
  console.log({index, toEdit});
  setIdentity(toEdit);
}
```

Use a functional state update to access and update from the previous state value. Map the previous state to a new array and create a new object reference for the `identity` object you are updating.

```
function handleChange(evt) {
  setIdentity(identity => identity.map(el => el.id === 1 ? {
    ...el,
    name: "Michel"
  } : el));
}
```

[image: Edit react-does-not-render-new-states-at-their-updates]

Answer (score 0):

As @DBS and @secan said, I got confused with the state update.

This code works :

```js
 function handleChange(evt) {
    const toEdit = [...identity]; // this line
    const index = toEdit.findIndex(predicate => predicate.id = 1);
    toEdit[index] = {...toEdit[index], name: "Michel"}
    console.log({index, toEdit});
    setIdentity(() => toEdit);
  }
```

When I create my copy, I have to create a new table (with the spread operator for example).

Thanks !